# Showing Multiple Lines in a TextView

Tags: ios, swift

I am doing a project in Swift and I am reading data from a file and trying to display it in a text view. I am reading it line by line. For example, if I have 10 lines in the file the text view only shows the last one. And I'd like to see them all.

How can I do that?

I am doing it like this:

```
if let aStreamReader = StreamReader(path:    "historic.txt") {
    defer {
        aStreamReader.close()
    }

while let line = aStreamReader.nextLine() {
    MyTextView.text = "\(line)"
}
```

The code is working in the console, because if I make a print every show up ok.
But in the text view only last line is visible.

Comment: you'll need to append the text together or collect it in an array and then display it after reading the file. currently it looks like you just set the text following each line encountered, thus only displaying the last line at runtime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about trying:

MyTextView.text **+**= "(line)"

The '+' will append rather than replace.

You might have to add \n after the lines string to create a new line:

MyTextView.text += "(line) \n"

**Update:**

I forgot you can't append onto a textview, so instead create an empty string before the loop and then append the line onto the string in the while loop. Then finally set the textview text to the totalString variable after the loop:

```
var totalString = ""
while let line = aStreamReader.nextLine() {
   totalString  = totalString + line + "\n"
}
MyTextView.text = totalString
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I get this message saying that binary operator += cannot be aplied to a string...

Comment: And this one is not memory efficient

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the value of `lines` property of label is `0` and try this

```
if let aStreamReader = StreamReader(path:    "historic.txt") {
defer {
    aStreamReader.close()
}
var str = ""
while let line = aStreamReader.nextLine() {
    str = str + line + "\n"
}
MyTextView.text = str
```